# How to create a listbox having index numbers followed with list item

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listbox

In Winforms I wanted to show a list box having item index number and item exactly as shown in the below [image: Figure]. I have gone through many SO links and also many articles also, most of them are using ListView instead of ListBox and also instead of showing List Item index they showing Image+ Item in it. I am ok with the listview but my objective is to show the Items with their corresponding index and on select it should give me the item only. Can anybody provide me any link or idea to achieve this in Winform using C#.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think best option for you is using `DataGridView` with two columns:

- `DataGridViewButtonColumn`, AutoSizeMode = AllCells
- `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`, ReadOnly = true, AutoSizeMode = Fill

Also `RowHeadersVisible` and `ColumnHeadersVisible` to false. Result:

[image]

Code:

```
string[] members = { "Beverages", "Condiments", "Confections" };
dataGridView1.DataSource = members.Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Index = i })
                                  .ToList();
```

Also you need to set columns `DataPropertyName` to Index and Value.

UPDATE (for .NET 2.0):

```
string[] members = { "Beverages", "Condiments", "Confections" };
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGridView1.DataSource = members;
```

Subscribe to CellFormatting event:

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, 
                                  DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        e.Value = e.RowIndex;
        return;
    }

    e.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share some link or detail description.

Comment: @Turtleneck I've added an image of result you'll get with DataGridView.

Comment: please share the running sample, I am not able to achieve the goal as my code is using .net framework version 2.0 and I can not upgrade it also.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your Listbox

Following link will guide you right direction.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15464/Extending-the-ListBox-to-show-more-complex-items

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider setting the DrawMode property on the listbox to DrawMode.Manual and handle the drawing of the items in your code.

Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drawmode.aspx